# AJAX Passing Variable to PHP

Tags: php, ajax

Wits end on this one.  I'm trying to use AJAX to pass a variable (table) over to PHP ($Table) to control a parameter of a SQL Query, but PHP outputs the variable ($Table) as null.

What am I doing wrong here?

```
<?php $Table = $_POST[table];?>

<p class="tab">The number of records in the <?php echo $Table?> table is: 
   <?PHP
     $sql="SELECT * FROM $Table";
     $result=mysqli_query($connect,$sql);
     $records=mysqli_num_rows($result);
     echo($records);
   ?>
</p>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    var table = "Members";

    $.ajax({
    method:"POST",
    data:{table:table},
    });
    });

  </script>
```

Comment: That php code is on same page where ajax is ?

Comment: Yes.  This code is all from the same page, which is why I didn't specify a URL.

Comment: Put `isset` around your `$_POST..` .Also add `success function` inside ajax call inside this response will come back (your html or echo codes) and then append same result to your `dom`.

Comment: Are you sure it’s not complaining about a null offset?   `$_POST[table]` should be `$_POST['table']`

Comment: Furthermore, the first time you run the script, the post value will be null. Therefore you must check if it exists, and  only then do the query. Also, post is the wrong verb to use if you are just reading; post is for *changing* data, and should always redirect afterward (see post-redirect-get pattern).

Comment: Warning! Your SQL is wide open to injection. Always use parameterized queries. Never insert a php variable into a query.

Comment: Wow, good to know.  It looks like I have some homework to do.

Comment: Tim, thank you again.  This has been very enlightening and frightening.

Answer (score 0):

**PHP Code :**

```
<?php
   if(isset($_GET["table"])){
     $table = $_GET["table"];
     echo "<h2>".$table."</h2>";
   }
?>
```

**jQuery / AJAX Code :**

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    var table = "Members";
    $.ajax({
    type:"GET",
    data:{table:table},
    success: function( data ) {
            console.log( data );
        }
    });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I pasted this code exactly as you typed it into a new page, and $table still returns null a value of null.